# Is there any way to implement chart in Lightning component apart from using external library?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

Can we include charts in lightning component without using any external library? I was looking into lightning design systems but did not find any thing relevant to it.

Comment: It is a lot of work to draw a chart hence the usual choice is to use a library where someone has already invested that effort. Perhaps the platform will supply a component in the future (but that could be a long time in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try appExchange components for that:

[Charts.js](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q5ADEAY)

[Report Chart](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qEVjEAM)